# MobileFirst Adapters and Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MobileFirst offers out of the box the possibility to invoke REST Services by server components written in plain Javascript, so called 'Adapters'. Since my app contains a lot of business logic inside them, I  need to test it by Unit Test. 
Could somebody suggest me a good framework how to create Unit Testing for 'server side' Javascript ? 
Thanks.

Comment: https://mochajs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own tests as mentioned in this post : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/26/MobileFirst-adapters-automatic-testing/ .

Alternatively swagger UI and Postman can also be used as mentioned here : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_testing_adapters.html